# Extensionless url .htaccess not accepting get tags

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have got this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?prequest=$1 [L]
```

and that works fine, but how do i need to edit the rewrite rule to also attach the specified part of the message past the ?, does anyone know what needs to be done to get it to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the [Query String Append](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) flag, it will append the `?x=y` part of the original URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?prequest=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `QSA` inside the brackets at the end of your RewriteRule so that it looks like: `[L,QSA]`